# Button color change based on condition in ngclass in Angular6

Tags: material-design, angular6, angular-ng-class

If i click the button it will change the color in to orange but by requirement is after click the same button it need to change into default color. so please guid me to do this.

```
  <button #val1 class="mat-raised-button" [ngClass]="{'orange': val1.value==current_product_size}" (click)="sizeFilter(val1.value)" value="375ML">375ML</button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
sizeFilter(size_clicked) {
    this.current_product_size = size_clicked
}
```

Comment: P.S. You're supposed to use the `mat-raised-button` attribute instead of the class. This is to apply the appropriate ripple. (Unless if you don't want the ripple - use the `disableRipple` attribute)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**You can give more than one ngClasses if you want like this** 


<button #val1 class="mat-raised-button" 
[ngClass]="{'toggleColor': toggleColor,'orange': val1.value==current_product_size}" 
(click)="sizeFilter(val1.value)" 
value="375ML">375ML</button>
```

**Component**

```
toggleColor = false;
sizeFilter(size_clicked) {
this.toggleColor = !this.toggleColor;
this.current_product_size = size_clicked
}
```

**CSS**

```
.toggleColor{
  background: yourDefaultColor !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html:

```
 <button #val1 class="mat-raised-button" [ngClass]="{'orange': isOrange}" (click)="setOrange()">375ML</button>
```

Your component:

```
isOrange = false;

setOrange() {
    isOrange = !isOrange;
}
```